# Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to make this simple website for practice. I am running into the error "SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected" , and am not sure how to fix it. I am trying to create a new componet called app which will allow me to just call 'ReactDOM.render()' to make my page. Any help? thanks in advance!

```js
            <head>

          <title>ICS 211 - React</title>
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
          <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
          <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
          <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
          <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <style>
              html {
                background - color: #f8f8f8;
              font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            }
              hr {
                color: blue;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
          <body>
            <div id="container"></div>
            <script type="text/babel">
              const TITLE =() =>{
            return <div>
                <h1>My Top 3 Movies</h1>
                <h3>fun name</h3>
              </div>;
              }
          const MOVIE =({name, link}) => {
            
            
            return <li >{name}<a href={link}>{link}</a></li>
              }
            
            
          const App=()=>{
                <div>

                  <TITLE />
                  <ol>


                    <MOVIE name="Boyz n the Hood: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101507/" />
                    <MOVIE name="The Shawshank Redemption: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/" />
                    <MOVIE name="World War Z: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816711/" />

                  </ol>
                </div> , document.getElementById('container');
            
              }
            
          ReactDOM.render(<App />);
            
        </script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, problem in order of scripts and App Container Component declaration

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
 <title>ICS 211 - React</title>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
   html {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   }
   hr {
    color: blue;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
 const TITLE =() =>{
  return <div>
  <h1>My Top 3 Movies</h1>
  <h3>fun name</h3>
  </div>;
  }
 const MOVIE =({name,link}) => {
  
  
  return <li >{name}<a href={link}>{link}</a></li>
 }


 const App=()=>(
  <div>
  
  <TITLE />
   <ol>
   
   
    <MOVIE name="Boyz n the Hood: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101507/" />
    <MOVIE name="The Shawshank Redemption: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/" />
    <MOVIE name="World War Z: " link="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816711/" />
    
   </ol>
 </div>);
 
  
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```